# How to use jquery to achieve the switching effect of jump

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a problem but my thoughts are knotted, I want to get help here!

"Requirement"

when the mouse hoveres to the yellow block, the blue block should be slowly slid down from its original place.
When the mouse leaves, the blue block can be slowly folded upwards.

I don’t know how to write it here, it’s easier?

Thank you everyone for watching my question, and thank you again.

```js
$(document).scroll(function(){

    var scrollH=$(document).scrollTop();
    if(scrollH > 60){
      $('.nav').addClass('up');
      $('.nav2').addClass('down');
    }else if(scrollH < 90){
       $('.nav').removeClass('up');
       $('.nav2').removeClass('down');
    }
})



$(function() {
  $(".nav2").on("mouseover", function() {
    window.scrollTo(0,0);
  });
})


//Here is the code I am trying to complete
$(function(){
  $('.nav').mouseenter().css({
    'top':'100px',
    'transition':'1s',
  });
})
```

```css
.header {
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: red;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 60px;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 2;
}

.nav2 {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: #e5d549;
  color: #222;
  padding: 20px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 80px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}
.nav2.down {
  -webkit-animation: fadeIn 1s forwards;
          animation: fadeIn 1s forwards;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  z-index: 2;
}
.nav2 .breadcrumb {
  display: flex;
}
.nav2 .breadcrumb .item::after {
  content: ">";
  padding: 0px 8px;
}
.nav2 .breadcrumb .item::after:last-child {
  display: none;
}
.nav2 .search {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid #222;
  padding: 3px;
}
.nav2 .search .fas {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 6px;
}
.nav2 .search .btn {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 2px;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #e5d549;
  color: #222;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin-left: 3px;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
.nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-color: #1768ac;
  padding: 20px;
  z-index: 1;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.nav.up {
  -webkit-animation: fadeout 1s forwards;
          animation: fadeout 1s forwards;
}
.nav .filter {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  order: 1;
  color: #fff;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}
.nav .filter .item {
  margin: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
}
.nav .category {
  display: flex;
  order: 2;
}
.nav .category .item {
  color: #fff;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
.nav .search {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 3px;
  order: 3;
}
.nav .search .fas {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 6px;
}
.nav .search .btn {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 2px;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #e5d549;
  color: #222;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin-left: 3px;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeout {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes fadeout {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
.content {
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #222;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="header">LOGO</div>


<!-- 第一個顯示的畫面 -->
<div class="nav">
  <ul class="filter">
    <li class="item">hot</li>
    <li class="item">NEW</li>
 </ul>
  <ul class="category">
    <li class="item">item</li>
    <li class="item">item</li>
    <li class="item">item</li>
    <li class="item">item</li>
    <li class="item">item</li>
    <li class="item">item</li>
  </ul>
  <div class="search">
    <label><i class="fas fa-search"></i></label>
    <input class="search_input" type="text" >
    <a  class="btn" href="javascript:;">BTN</a>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- 滑動後會顯示的畫面 -->
<div class="nav2">
  <ul class="breadcrumb">
    <li class="item">item</li>
    <li class="item">item</li>
    <li class="item">item</li>
  </ul>
   <div class="search">
      <label><i class="fas fa-search"></i></label>
      <input class="search_input" type="text" >
      <a  class="btn" href="javascript:;">BTN</a>
    </div>
</div>
  <div class="content">
  Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita vitae dolores accusantium voluptas facilis sint corporis, soluta esse nostrum culpa voluptatem temporibus est quidem adipisci laboriosam, mollitia suscipit nobis eveniet tenetur maxime! Explicabo quos, vitae officia commodi asperiores nobis dolorem mollitia minima reiciendis praesentium porro, eum soluta fuga. Eius dolorum debitis reprehenderit aut provident maiores iusto inventore molestiae tempora beatae fugit itaque hic, ad illo accusamus id quasi harum quis amet, incidunt nostrum nam. Expedita, nostrum. Enim, aperiam. Illum alias iure quas illo sint, deleniti optio porro velit deserunt! Quasi molestiae, nisi doloremque veniam earum veritatis libero ea assumenda est.
    Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita vitae dolores accusantium voluptas facilis sint corporis, soluta esse nostrum culpa voluptatem temporibus est quidem adipisci laboriosam, mollitia suscipit nobis eveniet tenetur maxime! Explicabo quos, vitae officia commodi asperiores nobis dolorem mollitia minima reiciendis praesentium porro, eum soluta fuga. Eius dolorum debitis reprehenderit aut provident maiores iusto inventore molestiae tempora beatae fugit itaque hic, ad illo accusamus id quasi harum quis amet, incidunt nostrum nam. Expedita, nostrum. Enim, aperiam. Illum alias iure quas illo sint, deleniti optio porro velit deserunt! Quasi molestiae, nisi doloremque veniam earum veritatis libero ea assumenda est.Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita vitae dolores accusantium voluptas facilis sint corporis, soluta esse nostrum culpa voluptatem temporibus est quidem adipisci laboriosam, mollitia suscipit nobis eveniet tenetur maxime! Explicabo quos, vitae officia commodi asperiores nobis dolorem mollitia minima reiciendis praesentium porro, eum soluta fuga. Eius dolorum debitis reprehenderit aut provident maiores iusto inventore molestiae tempora beatae fugit itaque hic, ad illo accusamus id quasi harum quis amet, incidunt nostrum nam. Expedita, nostrum. Enim, aperiam. Illum alias iure quas illo sint, deleniti optio porro velit deserunt! Quasi molestiae, nisi doloremque veniam earum veritatis libero ea assumenda est.Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita vitae dolores accusantium voluptas facilis sint corporis, soluta esse nostrum culpa voluptatem temporibus est quidem adipisci laboriosam, mollitia suscipit nobis eveniet tenetur maxime! Explicabo quos, vitae officia commodi asperiores nobis dolorem mollitia minima reiciendis praesentium porro, eum soluta fuga. Eius dolorum debitis reprehenderit aut provident maiores iusto inventore molestiae tempora beatae fugit itaque hic, ad illo accusamus id quasi harum quis amet, incidunt nostrum nam. Expedita, nostrum. Enim, aperiam. Illum alias iure quas illo sint, deleniti optio porro velit deserunt! Quasi molestiae, nisi doloremque veniam earum veritatis libero ea assumenda est.Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita vitae dolores accusantium voluptas facilis sint corporis, soluta esse nostrum culpa voluptatem temporibus est quidem adipisci laboriosam, mollitia suscipit nobis eveniet tenetur maxime! Explicabo quos, vitae officia commodi asperiores nobis dolorem mollitia minima reiciendis praesentium porro, eum soluta fuga. Eius dolorum debitis reprehenderit aut provident maiores iusto inventore molestiae tempora beatae fugit itaque hic, ad illo accusamus id quasi harum quis amet, incidunt nostrum nam. Expedita, nostrum. Enim, aperiam. Illum alias iure quas illo sint, deleniti optio porro velit deserunt! Quasi molestiae, nisi doloremque veniam earum veritatis libero ea assumenda est.lorem100Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita vitae dolores accusantium voluptas facilis sint corporis, soluta esse nostrum culpa voluptatem temporibus est quidem adipisci laboriosam, mollitia suscipit nobis eveniet tenetur maxime! Explicabo quos, vitae officia commodi asperiores nobis dolorem mollitia minima reiciendis praesentium porro, eum soluta fuga. Eius dolorum debitis reprehenderit aut provident maiores iusto inventore molestiae tempora beatae fugit itaque hic, ad illo accusamus id quasi harum quis amet, incidunt nostrum nam. Expedita, nostrum. Enim, aperiam. Illum alias iure quas illo sint, deleniti optio porro velit deserunt! Quasi molestiae, nisi doloremque veniam earum veritatis libero ea assumenda est.Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita vitae dolores accusantium voluptas facilis sint corporis, soluta esse nostrum culpa voluptatem temporibus est quidem adipisci laboriosam, mollitia suscipit nobis eveniet tenetur maxime! Explicabo quos, vitae officia commodi asperiores nobis dolorem mollitia minima reiciendis praesentium porro, eum soluta fuga. Eius dolorum debitis reprehenderit aut provident maiores iusto inventore molestiae tempora beatae fugit itaque hic, ad illo accusamus id quasi harum quis amet, incidunt nostrum nam. Expedita, nostrum. Enim, aperiam. Illum alias iure quas illo sint, deleniti optio porro velit deserunt! Quasi molestiae, nisi doloremque veniam earum veritatis libero ea assumenda est.Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita vitae dolores accusantium voluptas facilis sint corporis, soluta esse nostrum culpa voluptatem temporibus est quidem adipisci laboriosam, mollitia suscipit nobis eveniet tenetur maxime! Explicabo quos, vitae officia commodi asperiores nobis dolorem mollitia minima reiciendis praesentium porro, eum soluta fuga. Eius dolorum debitis reprehenderit aut provident maiores iusto inventore molestiae tempora beatae fugit itaque hic, ad illo accusamus id quasi harum quis amet, incidunt nostrum nam. Expedita, nostrum. Enim, aperiam. Illum alias iure quas illo sint, deleniti optio porro velit deserunt! Quasi molestiae, nisi doloremque veniam earum veritatis libero ea assumenda est.
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it's not jquery I think it does what you want. Your button placement cause the blue and yellow divs to go beyond the screen because of your padding. You'll want to clean that up. You can change the transition times and also have different times by not using `all` but rather listed `opacity` and `height` separalty.

```js
let nav = document.getElementById("nav");
let navBounds = nav.getBoundingClientRect();
let nav2 = document.getElementById("nav2");
let nav2Bounds = nav2.getBoundingClientRect();
let bodyBounds = document.body.getBoundingClientRect();
let content = document.getElementById("content");
let contentBounds = content.getBoundingClientRect();

window.addEventListener("scroll", (e) => {
  navBounds = nav.getBoundingClientRect();
  nav2Bounds = nav2.getBoundingClientRect();
  bodyBounds = document.body.getBoundingClientRect();
  contentBounds = content.getBoundingClientRect();

  if (window.scrollY == 0) {
    nav.style.height = "min-content";
    nav.style.opacity = "1";
    nav2.style.height = "0";
    nav2.style.opacity = "0";
    content.style.top = 60 + navBounds.y + navBounds.height + "px";
  } else if (e) {
    nav.style.height = "0";
    nav.style.opacity = "0";
    nav2.style.height = "50px";
    nav2.style.opacity = "1";
  }
});

nav2.addEventListener("mouseover", (e) => {
  nav.style.height = "min-content";
  nav.style.opacity = "1";
  nav2.style.height = "0";
  nav2.style.opacity = "0";
});
```

```css
.header {
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: red;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 60px;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 2;
}

.nav2 {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: #e5d549;
  color: #222;
  height: 0;
  padding: 20px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 80px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  transition: all 0.5s linear;
}

.nav2 .breadcrumb {
  display: flex;
}
.nav2 .breadcrumb .item::after {
  content: ">";
  padding: 0px 8px;
}
.nav2 .breadcrumb .item::after:last-child {
  display: none;
}
.nav2 .search {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid #222;
  padding: 3px;
}
.nav2 .search .fas {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 6px;
}
.nav2 .search .btn {
  display: inline-block;
  left: -20px;
  padding: 2px;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #e5d549;
  color: #222;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin-left: 3px;
}

.nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 80px;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: min-content;
  background-color: #1768ac;
  padding: 20px;
  z-index: 1;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  transition: all 1s linear;
}

.nav .filter {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  order: 1;
  color: #fff;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}
.nav .filter .item {
  margin: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
}
.nav .category {
  display: flex;
  order: 2;
}
.nav .category .item {
  color: #fff;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
.nav .search {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 3px;
  order: 3;
}
.nav .search .fas {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 6px;
}
.nav .search .btn {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 2px;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #e5d549;
  color: #222;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin-left: 3px;
}

.content {
  position: relative;
  top: 220px;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #222;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="header">LOGO</div>

  <!-- 第一個顯示的畫面 -->
  <div class="nav" id="nav">
    <ul class="filter">
      <li class="item">hot</li>
      <li class="item">NEW</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="category">
      <li class="item">item</li>
      <li class="item">item</li>
      <li class="item">item</li>
      <li class="item">item</li>
      <li class="item">item</li>
      <li class="item">item</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="search">
      <label><i class="fas fa-search"></i></label>
      <input class="search_input" type="text">
      <a class="btn" href="javascript:;">BTN</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- 滑動後會顯示的畫面 -->
  <div class="nav2" id='nav2'>
    <ul class="breadcrumb">
      <li class="item">item</li>
      <li class="item">item</li>
      <li class="item">item</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="search">
      <label><i class="fas fa-search"></i></label>
      <input class="search_input" type="text">
      <a class="btn" href="javascript:;">BTN</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content" id='content'>
    Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita vitae dolores accusantium voluptas facilis sint corporis, soluta esse nostrum culpa voluptatem temporibus est quidem adipisci laboriosam, mollitia suscipit nobis eveniet tenetur maxime! Explicabo quos, vitae officia commodi asperiores nobis dolorem mollitia minima reiciendis praesentium porro, eum soluta fuga. Eius dolorum debitis reprehenderit aut provident maiores iusto inventore molestiae tempora beatae fugit itaque hic, ad illo accusamus id quasi harum quis amet, incidunt nostrum nam. Expedita, nostrum. Enim, aperiam. Illum alias iure quas illo sint, deleniti optio porro velit deserunt! Quasi molestiae, nisi doloremque veniam earum veritatis libero ea assumenda est.
    Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita vitae dolores accusantium voluptas facilis sint corporis, soluta esse nostrum culpa voluptatem temporibus est quidem adipisci laboriosam, mollitia suscipit nobis eveniet tenetur maxime! Explicabo quos, vitae officia commodi asperiores nobis dolorem mollitia minima reiciendis praesentium porro, eum soluta fuga. Eius dolorum debitis reprehenderit aut provident maiores iusto inventore molestiae tempora beatae fugit itaque hic, ad illo accusamus id quasi harum quis amet, incidunt nostrum nam. Expedita, nostrum. Enim, aperiam. Illum alias iure quas illo sint, deleniti optio porro velit deserunt! Quasi molestiae, nisi doloremque veniam earum veritatis libero ea assumenda est.Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita vitae dolores accusantium voluptas facilis sint corporis, soluta esse nostrum culpa voluptatem temporibus est quidem adipisci laboriosam, mollitia suscipit nobis eveniet tenetur maxime! Explicabo quos, vitae officia commodi asperiores nobis dolorem mollitia minima reiciendis praesentium porro, eum soluta fuga. Eius dolorum debitis reprehenderit aut provident maiores iusto inventore molestiae tempora beatae fugit itaque hic, ad illo accusamus id quasi harum quis amet, incidunt nostrum nam. Expedita, nostrum. Enim, aperiam. Illum alias iure quas illo sint, deleniti optio porro velit deserunt! Quasi molestiae, nisi doloremque veniam earum veritatis libero ea assumenda est.Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita vitae dolores accusantium voluptas facilis sint corporis, soluta esse nostrum culpa voluptatem temporibus est quidem adipisci laboriosam, mollitia suscipit nobis eveniet tenetur maxime! Explicabo quos, vitae officia commodi asperiores nobis dolorem mollitia minima reiciendis praesentium porro, eum soluta fuga. Eius dolorum debitis reprehenderit aut provident maiores iusto inventore molestiae tempora beatae fugit itaque hic, ad illo accusamus id quasi harum quis amet, incidunt nostrum nam. Expedita, nostrum. Enim, aperiam. Illum alias iure quas illo sint, deleniti optio porro velit deserunt! Quasi molestiae, nisi doloremque veniam earum veritatis libero ea assumenda est.Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita vitae dolores accusantium voluptas facilis sint corporis, soluta esse nostrum culpa voluptatem temporibus est quidem adipisci laboriosam, mollitia suscipit nobis eveniet tenetur maxime! Explicabo quos, vitae officia commodi asperiores nobis dolorem mollitia minima reiciendis praesentium porro, eum soluta fuga. Eius dolorum debitis reprehenderit aut provident maiores iusto inventore molestiae tempora beatae fugit itaque hic, ad illo accusamus id quasi harum quis amet, incidunt nostrum nam. Expedita, nostrum. Enim, aperiam. Illum alias iure quas illo sint, deleniti optio porro velit deserunt! Quasi molestiae, nisi doloremque veniam earum veritatis libero ea assumenda est.lorem100Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita vitae dolores accusantium voluptas facilis sint corporis, soluta esse nostrum culpa voluptatem temporibus est quidem adipisci laboriosam, mollitia suscipit nobis eveniet tenetur maxime! Explicabo quos, vitae officia commodi asperiores nobis dolorem mollitia minima reiciendis praesentium porro, eum soluta fuga. Eius dolorum debitis reprehenderit aut provident maiores iusto inventore molestiae tempora beatae fugit itaque hic, ad illo accusamus id quasi harum quis amet, incidunt nostrum nam. Expedita, nostrum. Enim, aperiam. Illum alias iure quas illo sint, deleniti optio porro velit deserunt! Quasi molestiae, nisi doloremque veniam earum veritatis libero ea assumenda est.Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita vitae dolores accusantium voluptas facilis sint corporis, soluta esse nostrum culpa voluptatem temporibus est quidem adipisci laboriosam, mollitia suscipit nobis eveniet tenetur maxime! Explicabo quos, vitae officia commodi asperiores nobis dolorem mollitia minima reiciendis praesentium porro, eum soluta fuga. Eius dolorum debitis reprehenderit aut provident maiores iusto inventore molestiae tempora beatae fugit itaque hic, ad illo accusamus id quasi harum quis amet, incidunt nostrum nam. Expedita, nostrum. Enim, aperiam. Illum alias iure quas illo sint, deleniti optio porro velit deserunt! Quasi molestiae, nisi doloremque veniam earum veritatis libero ea assumenda est.Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita vitae dolores accusantium voluptas facilis sint corporis, soluta esse nostrum culpa voluptatem temporibus est quidem adipisci laboriosam, mollitia suscipit nobis eveniet tenetur maxime! Explicabo quos, vitae officia commodi asperiores nobis dolorem mollitia minima reiciendis praesentium porro, eum soluta fuga. Eius dolorum debitis reprehenderit aut provident maiores iusto inventore molestiae tempora beatae fugit itaque hic, ad illo accusamus id quasi harum quis amet, incidunt nostrum nam. Expedita, nostrum. Enim, aperiam. Illum alias iure quas illo sint, deleniti optio porro velit deserunt! Quasi molestiae, nisi doloremque veniam earum veritatis libero ea assumenda est.
  </div>
</div>
```